# How do I use 2 conditions in Pandas Filter

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out all the values that match the pattern. However I would also like to include one more condtion which is

```
~df["email"].str.contains("missing")

email_filt = df['email'].str.match("^[A-Za-z1-9_!#%&*\$][A-Za-z0-9_!#%&*\$\.]+@\w+\.\w{2,16}$")
```

How do i combine these two statements into email_filt.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use df.loc where it allows you to use boolean indexing here's an example of it

```
>>> df=pandas.DataFrame({'email':['example1@domain1.com','example2@domain2.com','example3@domain3.com','missing1','missing2','awesome_email@awesome_domain.com']}) 
>>> print(df)                                                                                                                                                      
                              email
0              example1@domain1.com
1              example2@domain2.com
2              example3@domain3.com
3                          missing1
4                          missing2
5  awesome_email@awesome_domain.com
>>> df.loc[~df['email'].str.contains('missing')] 
                              email
0              example1@domain1.com
1              example2@domain2.com
2              example3@domain3.com
5  awesome_email@awesome_domain.com
>>> df.loc[(~df['email'].str.contains('missing')) & df['email'].str.match("awesome")]
                              email
5  awesome_email@awesome_domain.com
```

Now adjust it to your exercise!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
con1 = ~df["email"].str.contains("missing")
email_filt = df['email'].str.match("^[A-Za-z1-9_!#%&*\$][A-Za-z0-9_!#%&*\$\.]+@\w+\.\w{2,16}$")
out = df[con1 & email_filt]
```

Comment: I am getting this error : IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).